# Unity 5.4.3p4 Vungle Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, vungle-ads

```
Unity 5.4.3p4
Google services 10.0.1
```

I am trying to integrate Vungle Ads in unity. After converting Unity to Android studio project, Vungle not initialized when I try to run it in device. I think its something to do with Google Play Services version. Which version should I use ?

**Getting the below error.**

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.vungle.publisher.tr>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks;
    at void com.vungle.publisher.to.<init>() (vungle:46)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.tp.get() (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sp.get() (vungle:10)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.tl.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.ta.a(com.vungle.publisher.tj) (vungle:4530)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.tj.<init>() (vungle:22)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.tk.get() (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sq.get() (vungle:10)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zq.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zp.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zh.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zg.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zn.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zm.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zd.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:14)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zc.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.co.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:11)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.cn.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.m.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:10)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.l.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.f.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:21)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.e.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:133)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:18)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.ta.a(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:4515)
    at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:97)
    at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:33)
    at void com.vungle.VunglePlugin$2.run() (VunglePlugin.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-vunglePub_48221f1314ef40c57721f014fe98a621092beedd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-vunglePlugin_38d6e44214e1cfed631c1e8d3d0cd30a63bee13e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unitydialogplugin_7ed729654a9a03c706b8f6e28768824e4c24822f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unityadsrelease-unspecified-jars_78049452539faaab6974dd57ba75175d325edf9f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unity-plugin-library_ac735c0b655adac41ec70f99ca449902e2ee56f1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unity-classes_24810cd9e
    at void com.vungle.publisher.to.<init>() (vungle:46)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.tp.get() (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sp.get() (vungle:10)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.tl.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.ta.a(com.vungle.publisher.tj) (vungle:4530)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.tj.<init>() (vungle:22)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.tk.get() (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sq.get() (vungle:10)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zq.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zp.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zh.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zg.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zn.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zm.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zd.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:14)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zc.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.co.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:11)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.cn.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.m.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:10)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.l.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.f.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:21)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.e.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:133)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:18)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.ta.a(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:4515)
    at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:97)
    at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:33)
    at void com.vungle.VunglePlugin$2.run() (VunglePlugin.java:110)
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.vungle.publisher.tr>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks;
    at void com.vungle.publisher.to.<init>() (vungle:46)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.tp.get() (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sp.get() (vungle:10)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.tl.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.ta.a(com.vungle.publisher.tj) (vungle:4530)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.tj.<init>() (vungle:22)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.tk.get() (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sq.get() (vungle:10)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zq.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zp.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zh.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zg.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zn.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zm.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zd.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:14)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zc.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.co.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:11)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.cn.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.m.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:10)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.l.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.f.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:21)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.e.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:133)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:18)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.ta.a(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:4515)
    at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:97)
    at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:33)
    at void com.vungle.VunglePlugin$2.run() (VunglePlugin.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-vunglePub_48221f1314ef40c57721f014fe98a621092beedd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-vunglePlugin_38d6e44214e1cfed631c1e8d3d0cd30a63bee13e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unitydialogplugin_7ed729654a9a03c706b8f6e28768824e4c24822f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unityadsrelease-unspecified-jars_78049452539faaab6974dd57ba75175d325edf9f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unity-plugin-library_ac735c0b655adac41ec70f99ca449902e2ee56f1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxx.games.xxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unity-classes_24810cd9e
    at void com.vungle.publisher.to.<init>() (vungle:46)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.tp.get() (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sp.get() (vungle:10)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.tl.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.ta.a(com.vungle.publisher.tj) (vungle:4530)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.tj.<init>() (vungle:22)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.tk.get() (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sq.get() (vungle:10)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zq.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zp.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zh.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zg.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zn.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:8)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zm.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.zd.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:14)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.zc.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.co.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:11)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.cn.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.m.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:10)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.l.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.f.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:21)
    at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.e.get() (vungle:8)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:133)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:18)
    at void com.vungle.publisher.ta.a(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:4515)
    at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:97)
    at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:33)
    at void com.vungle.VunglePlugin$2.run() (VunglePlugin.java:110)
```